# Upgrade MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.5 on VPS (OVH)

Tags: mysql, linux, upgrade, vps

I'm a starter to SSH-ing to VPS.

OVH VPS environment:

Server OS: CentOS 6.9

OVH Control Panel Release: 3.36

PHP: 5.6.31 (by default it was 5.3 and managed somehow to update)
I used, Yum Repository and RPM to upgrade PHP and worked. HOwever not sure the right syntax and repository for the MySQL.

MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Now my problem is; when I tried to upgrade MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.5 it's upgrading but breaking and fails to service mysqld start.

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Check the logs. All the logs.

Comment: Now that I have managed to update the MySQL :) however, when I login to phpmyadmin, it shows; •Server version: 5.5.57 - MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi. and •Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73. Not sure why one in old version and other in new version :(